# How to hide only one element in Vue webform

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm new to Vue and attempting to hide one element in a webform on load that is in a loop.  I'm attempting to use v-if with a showHideEditComponent method call.   When I call the showHideEditComponent method and set the uniqueName to "DescribeIssue" and return false it hides all the elements on the form.  If I set it to true it will only show the DescribeIsusse element.  How do I only hide DescribeIssue and keep all of the other elements entact without having if, if else, return true, return false.... in the showHideEditComponent method?

```
 <div v-for="field in Datas" :key="field.key" class="form-row">
          
            <component :is="getComponentName(field)" :Datas="field"
              :id="'input-ninci-data-' + field.id" v-model="
                    testSelectedRowForEdit.attributeValues[field.uniqueName]
                  " :changeLogInfo="
                    testSelectedRowForEdit.changeLogInfos[field.uniqueName]
                 " :useVueMultiSelect="field.listAllowMultiple" 
                 
                  //adding v-if here

                 v-if="showHideEditComponent(field.uniqueName)"
               @blur="onWebFormFieldUpdate">
            </component>
          
        </div>
        
        
showHideEditComponent(uniqueName) {

    if (uniqueName === 'DescribeIssue') {

      return false;     //hides all elements 
      //return true;    // only shows DescribeIssue element
    }
```

Comment: Do you return a boolean out of the `if` block too? Otherwise it will return `void` when it doesn't under the if, which is considered a falsy value, that's why it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add condition for DescribeIssue so when get DescribeIssue field so return false and not show DescribeIssue filed and for other fields you can pass true in else condition.

```
showHideEditComponent(uniqueName) {
    if (uniqueName === 'DescribeIssue') {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```